# Is there a way to combine datasets from multiple layers of subdirectories?

Tags: r, imagej

I have a large directory containing 4 layers of subdirectories. These are created based on the file name of the original image from which data was gathered. Example: Cell group 1, at 7 days, sample 1, image set 1 would be sorted into the folder: C:/me/Desktop/Test/C1/7d/N1/I1. I created a code to append all this into a new data set for every time period. However, my code isn't saving or creating anything, and it's also finding every layer of subdirectory at every step in the for loop. I'm not very experienced in R studio so i would love some help.

I tried using this code:

```
# Load the tidyverse library
library(tidyverse)

# Set the root directory
root_dir <- "C:/Users/me/Desktop/Test"

# Loop through each cell group
cell_groups <- list.dirs(root_dir, full.names = TRUE)
for (cimRPC in cell_groups) {
  # Get the cell group name from the folder name
  cell_group_name <- basename(cimRPC)
  # Loop through each time period
  nDOX <- list.dirs(cimRPC, full.names = TRUE)
  for (Days in nDOX) {
    # Get the time period from the folder name
    time_period <- as.numeric(gsub("d", "", basename(Days)))
    # Create an empty data frame to store the combined data
    combined_data <- data.frame(time_period = time_period)
    
    # Loop through each coverslip (N)
    NX <- list.dirs(Days, full.names = TRUE)
    for (Coverslips in NX) {
      # Loop through each imageset
      ImageSet <- list.dirs(Coverslips, full.names = TRUE)
      for (GroupNumber in ImageSet) {
        Image_Data <- list.files(GroupNumber, pattern = "_mGFP.csv")
        # Loop through each csv file
        for (dataset in Image_Data) {
          file_path <- file.path(GroupNumber, dataset)
          data <- read.csv(file_path)
          # Append the data to the combined_data data frame, making sure it has the same number of columns
          combined_data <- rbind(combined_data, data)
        }
      }
    }
    # Write the combined data frame to a .csv file
    write.csv(combined_data, file = file.path(cimRPC, paste0(cell_group_name, "_", time_period, ".csv")))
  }
}
```

However, it's giving me these errors:

```
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
In addition: Warning message:
In as.numeric(gsub("d", "", basename(Days))) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I am certain that the number of columns must match because imageJ created identical result tables for every measurement. So none of the .csv documents have any blocks with NA. Secondly i don't know why the time period from the folder name is failing to be converted to a numeric value. All the folders at the time period level have either: 0d, 3d, 5d, 7d, 10d, 12d, as name.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1st problem: have you verified by looking at a few of the csvs that they are actually identical? Even if you stipulate the columns in ImageJ, it is possible to generate CSVs with or without row numbers, which can lead to this error. When I load in csvs from ImageJ into R, I use a function to remove this column (if it's there) before doing `rbind`.

Comment: 2nd problem is hard to troubleshoot. I agree that your script should parse the day number out, but you need to look at nDOX etc in your code and confirm that they are pointing to the right object.

Answer (score 0):

With this line:

```
combined_data <- data.frame(time_period = time_period)
```

You make a data frame that has one row and one column. So when you do:

```
combined_data <- rbind(combined_data, data)
```

the number of columns do not match.

A better way to deal with this is to remove the line that creates `combined_data`. And now approach the problem like this (in the innermost loop).

```
  # Loop through each csv file
  for (dataset in Image_Data) {
    file_path <- file.path(GroupNumber, dataset)
    data <- read.csv(file_path)
    # append column with day (I think this is what you want to do?)
    data$time_period <- time_period
    # now check if this is the first file we are loading
    # this is one way, there are other ways to test...
    if(!exists(combined_data)) {
      combined_data <- data
    } else {
      # Append the data to the combined_data data frame, making sure it has the same number of columns
      combined_data <- rbind(combined_data, data)
    }
  }
```

For this to work, there needs to be no object called `combined_data` in your environment when you run your script. Either run the script in a fresh session, or remove it with `rm(combined_data)`